# Is it possible to plug a GPU on RAM slot?

Tags: gpu

So I was planning to modify my laptop to connect a GPU. And my laptop originally doesn’t have a GPU, not do it support thunderbolt. So I was planning if it’s possible to connect a GPU through DDR4 RAM slots. But since I can’t find any product on market supports that, I think I’ll have to wire it myself.

So I would like to ask is it possible to use a GPU connected on a RAM slot? If yes, how do I map it (cause I can’t find RAM slot‘s pin diagram on internet).

Comment: Only higher-end gaming/performance laptops will have a discrete [standalone] GPU, otherwise, it will have a GPU integrated onto the CPU.  If the CPU isn't soldered to the MB, you may be able to upgrade the CPU, possibly providing a boost on the integrated GPU.  The easiest way to boost performance is to increase RAM to max out the shared GPU RAM, while still having enough RAM left to not lower the performance of the PC _(budget price laptops will often be missing the RAM header for it's 2nd RAM slot - not sure if having a header soldered there would allow use of it)_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot do this.

A RAM slot is connected to a memory controller. A GPU is connected via a PCIe bus. Those two things are not compatible and are not able to be interconnected.

A GPU may contain memory chips, but it is not "simply" a memory device. A GPU is a specialised computer which requires a host machine to provide instructions and data in order for it to do work.

The slots might look like they have a similar number of pins, but that does not mean those pins perform the same function or work in even vaguely the same way.

The only way to connect a GPU into your laptop is if it has a mini PCIe slot or Thunderbolt/USB-C, which effectively uses PCIe lanes over USB to achieve the same.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible. RAM slots can only house RAM sticks.